# How do you have a variable inside of printed text, which was set earlier?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a noughts and crosses game in python, and I've forgotten how to have a variable within printed code. I know I can make my code more efficent by making the `O` and `X` parts merged but with the noughts and crosses board using variables to function.
What I have currently done:

```
for i in range (1,2):
player = int(input("Select from either `O` [1] or `X` [2]: "))
while player <0 or player >2:
    print("You must only enter 1 for noughts, or 2 for crosses.")
    time.sleep (0.5)
    user = int(input("Select from either `O` [1] or `X` [2]: "))
else:
    if player==1:
        user="O"
        time.sleep (0.25)
        print("Player 1 has selected to be `O`.") #user has chosen to be noughts
        time.sleep (1)
        print(" ")
        time.sleep (0.5)
        print(" You can choose a square by entering in the co-ordinates of it. ")
        time.sleep (1.5)
        print(" EG: If you selected (2,1) and you were `O`, the grid would look like: ")
        time.sleep (1.5)
        print("  (x>) [1] {2} [3]")
        print("      ┌-----------┐")
        print("  {1} |   | O |   |")
        print("      |---+---+---|")
        print("  [2] |   |   |   |")
        print("      |---+---+---|")
        print("  [3] |   |   |   |")
        print(" (y^) └-----------┘")
        print(" ")
    else:
        user="X"
        time.sleep (0.25)
        print("Player 1 has selected to be `X`.") #user has chosen to be crosses
        time.sleep (1)
        print(" ")
        time.sleep (0.5)
        print(" You can choose a square by entering in the co-ordinates of it. ")
        time.sleep (1.5)
        print(" EG: If you selected (2,1) and you were `X`, the grid would look like: ")
        time.sleep (1.5)
        print("  (x>) [1] {2} [3]")
        print("      ┌-----------┐")
        print("  {1} |   | X |   |")
        print("      |---+---+---|")
        print("  [2] |   |   |   |")
        print("      |---+---+---|")
        print("  [3] |   |   |   |")
        print(" (y^) └-----------┘")
        print(" ")

    time.sleep(1.5)
    print("Tutorial over, time to play!")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    x_axis=float(input("Please enter the x-axis: "))
    y_axis=float(input("Please enter the y-axis: "))
```

I think it works something like this, not correct, I know, please help!
`user=x`
`print("  [3] |   | {}  |   |".format{user}`

Comment: that should work fine ... if you are using python2 however i think you have to specify the argument position `{0}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a beginner, I would recommend just adding the variable to the to the `print()` function, for example:

```
x = 3
print("I have", x, "apples")
```

However, using the `.format()` is a lot more readable, like in your question:

```
user=x 
print("  [3] |   | {}  |   |".format{user}
```

This should print `x` in the middle column.